# Visualforce Controller test assertion fails

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, visualforce-component

I have a visualforce controller that populates a VF Gauge on a dashboard. I am working on the test as I got the gauge to look and work how I want. The problem is that when my test class runs the assertion fails I expect the value 1000 it returns 1.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class ISOGaugeControllerTeamYTD {
public Integer getMax2() {
    Decimal max1;
    List<AggregateResult> max =   [select sum(Goal__c) goal 
                            FROM ISO_Goal__c 
                            Where Goal__c != null 
                            AND Goal_Date__C = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR
                            AND RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'
                            AND ISO_Manager__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    if(max[0].get('goal') == null){
        max1 = 0;
        }
    else {
         max1 = (Decimal)max[0].get('goal');      
         }
    Integer max2 = (Integer)max1.divide(1000, 0);
    return max2;
    }

public List<gaugeData> getData() {
    List<gaugeData> data = new List<gaugeData>();
    List<AggregateResult> Actuals =   [select sum(amount__c) sum 
                                FROM Actuals__c 
                                Where Amount__c != null 
                                AND Actual_Date__c = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR
                                AND ISO_Goal__r.RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'                                    
                                AND ISO_Goal__r.ISO_Manager__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    if(actuals[0].get('sum') == null) {
        data.add(new gaugeData('Actual', 0));
        }     
        else {
             data.add(new gaugeData('Actual', (Integer)((Decimal)actuals[0].get('sum')).divide(1000, 0)));
             }
    return data;
}
// Wrapper class
public class gaugeData {

public String name { get; set; }
public Integer size { get; set; }

public gaugeData(String name, Integer data) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = data;
    }
}   
}
```

Test Class:

```
// Test Class for ISO dashboard gauge components
// Created By Dan Wooding
// Last Modified On: 5-11-16

@isTest
private class NPD_Test_ISOGaugeController {
@testSetup static void setup(){
    // Find Record Types
    List<RecordType> isoRT =    [Select Id FROM RecordType Where SobjectType = 'ISO_Goal__c' AND DeveloperName = 'Individual_Goal'];

    // Create ISO Goal record
    List<ISO_Goal__c> isoGoals = new List<ISO_Goal__c>();
        isoGoals.add(new ISO_Goal__c(
            Start_Date__c = System.today(),
            End_Date__c = System.today().addDays(30), 
            Goal__c = 1000,
            Goal_Date__c = System.today(),
            RecordTypeId = isoRT[0].Id,
            ISO_Manager__c = UserInfo.getUserId()
            ));
    insert isoGoals;
    System.debug('ISO Goals is:: ' + isoGoals);

    // Create Actual record
    List<Actuals__c> actuals = new List<Actuals__c>();
        actuals.add(new Actuals__c(
            Amount__c = 300,
            Actual_Date__c = System.today(),
            ISO_Goal__c = isoGoals[0].Id
            ));
    insert actuals;
    System.debug('Actual record is' + actuals);

}

public static testMethod void testTeamYTD() {
    // Required for vf pages
    PageReference pageRef = Page.ISOGaugeTeamYTD;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    // Get the records from the test Setup
    List<ISO_Goal__c> iso = [Select Goal__c FROM ISO_Goal__c];
    List<Actuals__c> act = [Select Amount__c FROM Actuals__c];
    System.debug('iso is:: ' + iso);
    System.debug('act is:: ' + act); 

    // Indstantiate a new controller
    ISOGaugeControllerTeamYTD controller = new ISOGaugeControllerTeamYTD();
    controller.getMax2();
    Integer max2 = controller.getMax2();
    System.debug('max2 is:: ' + max2);

    System.assertEquals(max2, 1000);

//      controller.getData();
//      data = controller.getData();
//      System.assertEquals(data, 300);
}
}
```

I've been reading other posts and the dev guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm) I think I am missing a part but I don't know what.

Comment: Always order the values `System.assertEquals(expected value, actual value);` to the assertion failure message represents what has happened.

Comment: Isn't the expected value 1 as you are dividing max1 by 1000 before returning?

Comment: I read the code the same as @joe does: you insert the value 1000 in the test and divide by 1000 in the controller so the result is 1.

Comment: Damn I forgot I started dividing the values yesterday. That's a good catch. It's passing that method now.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you add a method to normalize the data. You can test it quite simply, and it will be easier to be consistent.

```
public static Integer normalize(Decimal input)
{
    return (input == null) ? 0 : (Integer)input.divide(1000, 0)
}
```

Now you can have these two tests:

```
static final Decimal GOAL_INPUT = 5000;
static final Decimal GOAL_OUTPUT = 5;
static final Decimal GOAL_BLANK;

static testMethod void testNormalize()
{
    Test.startTest();
        Integer normalizedInput = MyClass.normalize(GOAL_INPUT);
        Integer normalizedBlank = MyClass.normalize(GOAL_BLANK);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(GOAL_OUTPUT, normalizedInput, 'The value should be adjusted');
    system.assertEquals(0, normalizedBlank, 'The value should be adjusted');
}
static testMethod void existingTestMethod()
{
    // use GOAL_INPUT in your testSetup
    // this test can still be valuable to make sure
    // you query and normalize properly
    system.assertEquals(GOAL_OUTPUT, controller.getMax2(), 'message');
}
```